# Pass dynamic values through GCP cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-scheduler

I need to trigger the Google dataflow jobs with the random/dynamic job_names from the cloud scheduler. I am able to pass the static job name and trigger the Dataflow by passing it in the scheduler body. Is there a way to dynamically set this job name through the scheduler?

If there is a way to set the current_timestamp or some random_numbers that would help.

I am aware that we can trigger the dataflow through the cloud function as well. But trying to avoid the no.of services here.

what I have:

`{ "job_name": "test-run-df-job" }`

What I need:

`{ "job_name": "test-run-df-job" + CURRENT_TIME() }`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you please update your post sharing your Cloud Scheduler job configuration, and indicating what is your target (app-engine, http or pubsub), where are you creating your job (gcloud, Cloud console, etc.), and where do you get the job names?

Comment: You can't add dynamic value in Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks that answered my question.

Answer (score 5):

You can't add dynamic value in Cloud Scheduler. You can imagine other services, like Cloud Workflows to do that addition without any code to write (like with a Cloud Functions for instance) and then invoke your Dataflow